# 230V Single phase connection for 2 HP Table saw to the breakers in the panel

Tags: electrical

For the 230V is the connection to the panel breakers made to L1 and L2 plus ground? This being two breakers side by side.

OR

Two L1 connections and ground? Breakers on opposite sides of the panel.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. In most panels, breakers side-by-side would be on opposite phases, and so would breakers on opposite side in the same row.

Comment: What type of electrical system (single phase, split-phase, three-phase, etc.)?

Comment: Most service panels I see have a double-comb arrangement - you've seen it - so both breakers in the same row get the same phase.  (lol, once I found an owner put 6 lighting circuits on the top 3 rows, for aesthetics - they were 3 MWBCs.)

Comment: @longneck What Wolf said. Your statement about breakers side by side (or one above the other) is correct however breakers on opposite sides in the same row will be on the same leg not opposites. Breakers #1 and #2 are on the same leg or phase.

Comment: You guys are right. I don't know what I was thinking. I had the comb in mind, but that didn't make it to the sentence forming part of my mind.

Answer (score 1):

With most panels 2 breakers side by side (not end to end) will provide 230V.
You should buy a breaker with a single handle 2 pole or get handle ties for 2 separate breakers.
You will also need the ground as you had mentioned. If a 20 amp motor you will need the wiring to be 12awg.
If 30A it will need to be 10awg. If you do use separate breakers with a handle tie make sure they are of the same amperage and style.
I just looked up 2 hp 230v motor it should draw 12A so it could be run off a 15A breaker with 14awg wire. but 20A would be better because on start up it may trip the 15A breaker.

Comment: When you say "motor" in sentence 4, you mean "breaker".

Comment: @Ed Beal You are correct about the motor drawing 12 amps. However according to Table 430.52, the OCPD for an inverse time breaker would be 250% of the table value so the breaker should be 30 amps. The wire though would be #14 wire since it is good for the 12 amp run current. The motor should have separate overload protection based on the nameplate FLA or internal thermal protection from the factory.

Comment: common motors like this usually have thermal overloads built into the motor

Comment: Wolf , Archonx I think I am correct in what I said, household type motors are rated in amps as they have thermal overloads, industrial motors require overload protection, I have 2 home compressors a 9 horse and a 5 horse the 5 horse takes 34 amps it is a single phase 220 industrial motor on a 40 amp breaker. The 9 220 horse is a "home appliance" type and only draws 26 amps  and is internally protected on a 30 amp bkr ,,, there are differences in the type and use of motors so code and tables don't always work unless we know the type

Comment: Thank you all for your time and response. The panel has a twin 40 Amp breaker. Would it be incorrect to use this breaker in lieu of purchasing a 30 Amp? Considering this as the motor has a thermal protection.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and response. The panel has a twin 40 Amp breaker. Would it be incorrect to use this breaker in lieu of purchasing a 30 Amp? Considering this as the motor has a thermal protection.

Comment: Frank, If you do use the 40A breaker wou will need to upsize to #8 wire and a larger outlet plug and cord. Depending on the brand of pannel it would be much cheaper to replace the 40 with a 30 the breaker will only cost ~15 USD the larger wire and outlet will cost much more.